# Finding $k$ such that $kx^2-5x+k=0$ has two distinct roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the number of values of $k$ in the interval $-6<k<-5 $ for which the equation
> $$kx^2-5x+k=0$$
> has 2 distinct roots.

My approach was to first find for what value of $k$ the equation will have same roots and then excluding this value of $k$. That is I got at $k= 25/4$ the equation will have equal roots.

Comment: What is the question?  What equation?  What is $k$?

Comment: What interval ?

Comment: The number of values of k in the interval -6<k<-5 for which the equation 
kx^2-5x+k=0 
has two distinct roots.

Comment: You can tell the number of real roots from the discriminant.  Is $k$ an integer?

Comment: $kx^2-5x+k=0$ has real distinct roots if discriminant $B^2 -4AC\gt0$

Now $B^2 -4AC \gt 0 \implies (-5)^2-4 k \cdot k \gt 0\implies 25-4k^2 \gt 0\implies |k| \lt\ \frac{5}{2}$

In $ -6<k<-5$, there is no $k$ for which  $kx^2-5x+k=0$ has real distinct roots

Comment: And if you are asking for distinct roots, complex or real, then you need the discriminant to be nonzero. The discriminant is zero if and only if $25-4k^2\neq 0$, if and only if $|k|\neq \frac{5}{2}$. Which would mean all values of $k$ in $(-6,-5)$ will do.

Comment: clarify: are complex roots allowed for x?  If so as @arturoMagidin says, any value of k between (-6, -5) will generate two distinct roots of x for the equation.
If x must be real, then there are no values of k with real roots for x.

Answer (score 1):

The discriminant is
$$25-4k^2.$$

The discriminant has to be positive so that there are two distinct solutions. That is, we have to solve the following inequality:

$$25>4k^2. $$

Taking the the square root of both sides we get $5>2|k|.$ Or 
$$|k|<\frac 52.$$

$k$ has to be negative because we are looking for solutions between $-6$ and $-5$. But the absolute value of the $k$s in this interval are greater than $\frac52$. So there are no such $k$s.

Comment: Also, note that if $k=-3$, then $25 < 4k^2$...  (pay attention when you take square roots).

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{4k^2} = 2|k|$.  It is only equals $2k$ when $k \geq 0$.